# Driver PDO para Postgres Docker, não instala

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, docker

Montei um ambiente PHP + Apache usando Docker (até ai tudo OK), porém, notei que o PHP não vem com o driver PDO_PGSQL instalado na imagem.. Pesquisei, achei algumas soluções mas não consegui instalar/rodar o driver.
Tentei até copiar um php.ini que eu já possuía, mas também não funcionou.

Segue abaixo meus arquivos:

## php.Dockerfile

```
# Imagem de origem
FROM php:7.1-fpm

# Mantenedor
LABEL maintainer="Gabriel.sistemasjr@gmail.com"

# tentei copiar o ini, tambem nao funcionou.
# ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

# ====== DRIVERS PHP ========
#
# -> PDO MYSQL
# RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql
#
# -> PDO POSTGRESQL
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql # Nao funciona
#
#
# tentei assim, porém, tambem nao funciona.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
&& apt-get clean
```

## apache.Dockerfile

```
# Imagem de origem
FROM php:apache

# Mantenedor
LABEL maintainer="Gabriel.sistemasjr@gmail.com"

# Setando o modo de reescrita de URL no apache.
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3" 
services:
# Servidor Apache
apache:
    build:
      dockerfile: apache.Dockerfile
      context: ./Docker/apache
    volumes:
      - "./app/src:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - php
    container_name: apache

  # Codigos da aplicação
  php:
    build:
      dockerfile: teste.Dockerfile
      context: ./Docker/php
    volumes:
      - "./app/src:/var/www/html"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    container_name: php
```

Mesmo seguindo alguns tutoriais, lendo a doc não consegui resolver o problema.
Os containers montam e não é retornado nenhum erro, porém, ao executar o phpInfo() vejo que o unico driver PDO existente é do sqlite.

No mais é isso, obrigado a quem puder ajudar!